# Eliminar un insert ya guardado

Tags: php, html5

el asunto que tengo es la creacion de un boton de "me gusta", cada me gusta de cada archivo tiene un id, tambien creé la table me_gusta para que cada like caiga con su id y el id del archivo al que dio me gusta.

Inserta en mi tabla, sin embargo al momento de volver a dar otro click en el me gusta, vuelve a insertar en la tabla de me gusta el mismo campo.

Estaba checando el archivo y logicamente entiendo que se debe comprobar si ya habia reaccionado antes o no a ese archivo, pero en la estructura en php, no encuentro como estructurarlo.

me serviria mucho su apoyo en este caso.

este es el archivo que guarda o elimina el registro al momento de reaccionar al me gusta. Originalmente iba actualizar el status, pero ahora solo debo quitar los UPDATES y agregar un delete, sin embargo no se donde ubicarlo, y con que condición seria.

---

```
$com="SELECT * FROM me_gusta where id_cancion='".$id."' AND user_id='".$user_id."'";
$comprobacion=mysqli_query($con,$com);
    if(!$comprobacion){/*there is existents of a song*/
        $gus="SELECT status FROM me_gusta where user_id='".$user_id."' and cancion='".$filename."'"; /*check like of user*/
        $gusta=mysqli_query($con,$gus);
        if($gusta){  
            $up= "UPDATE me_gusta SET status = '".$statusno."' WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' and cancion='".$filename."' and status= '".$status."';";
            $update=mysqli_query($con,$up);
            echo"ya le gustaba";
        }
        else{
            $up= "UPDATE me_gusta SET status = '".$status."' WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' and cancion='".$filename."' and status= '".$statusno."';";
            $update=mysqli_query($con,$up);
            echo"no le gustaba";
        }
    }
    elseif($comprobacion){   /*In this case doesnt exist a song with a like*/
        $in="INSERT INTO me_gusta(id_cancion,user_id,cancion,status) VALUES('".$id."','".$user_id. "','".$filename. "','".$status. "');";
        $insert=mysqli_query($con,$in);
        if ($insert) {
            echo "insertado";
        } else {
            echo "hubo un error";
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: Este codigo hace exactamente lo que pedis que haga.. por lo tanto, me parece que lo que no entedes es este codigo (lo copiaste de otro lado sin entenderlo?) pareceria que puede que te falte alguna de las variables? te fijaste que todo llegara ok?

Comment: No entendí. ¿Si le dio ya a me gusta qué debe ocurrir, no hacer nada o borrar / actualizar o qué? La explicación es algo confusa.